# Inconsistent datatypes: expected DATE got NUMBER - when inserting into DB

Tags: oracle, jdbc, prepared-statement

I'm trying to insert a row in a DB table and I keep getting

`ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected DATE got NUMBER`

I don't know why this is happening since all dates are SYSDATE

```
String insertNewAlarmStat =
        "insert into alarmes (id_alarm, alarm_key, id_notif, sever, urgency, date_hour_start, date_hour_modif, date_hour_end, " +
                "state, state_rec, date_hour_rec,  id_user_rec, id_system_rec, " +
                "type, cause, " +
                "num_events, id_entity_g, type_entity_g, " +
                "desc_entity_g, problem, " +
                "time_urg_act, max_urg_act, time_end, time_arq, lim, rec_oblig, dn, num_events_ps, id_alarm_o, id_notif_o, text_ad, domain, date_hour_reg) " +
                "values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, SYSDATE, SYSDATE, SYSDATE, SYSDATE, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, SYSDATE)";
PreparedStatement prpstmt = null ;
try {
        prpstmt = conn.prepareStatement(insertNewAlarmStat);

        prpstmt.setInt(1, randomNumberGenerator());
        prpstmt.setString(2, UUID.randomUUID().toString());
        prpstmt.setString(3, UUID.randomUUID().toString());
        prpstmt.setInt(4, randomNumberGenerator());
        prpstmt.setInt(5, 8);
        prpstmt.setInt(6, 8524);
        prpstmt.setString(7, UUID.randomUUID().toString());
        prpstmt.setString(8, UUID.randomUUID().toString());
        prpstmt.setString(9, UUID.randomUUID().toString());
        prpstmt.setString(10, UUID.randomUUID().toString());
        prpstmt.setString(11, "KABOOM");
        prpstmt.setInt(12, 8);
        prpstmt.setInt(13, 43);
        prpstmt.setString(14, UUID.randomUUID().toString());
        prpstmt.setString(15, UUID.randomUUID().toString());
        prpstmt.setString(16, UUID.randomUUID().toString());
        prpstmt.setString(17, UUID.randomUUID().toString());
        prpstmt.setInt(18, 2);
        prpstmt.setInt(19, 224);
        prpstmt.setInt(20, 2);
        prpstmt.setInt(21, 224);            
        prpstmt.setInt(22, 2);
        prpstmt.setInt(23, 224);            
        prpstmt.setInt(24, 2);  
        prpstmt.setString(25, UUID.randomUUID().toString());
        prpstmt.setString(26, UUID.randomUUID().toString());
        prpstmt.setString(27, UUID.randomUUID().toString());
        prpstmt.setInt(28, 2);

        prpstmt.executeUpdate();
} catch (SQLException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I've tryed this way and I've tryed to remove the SYSDATE's and add some:

`prpstmt.setDate(number, getCurrentDate()); //getCurrent date returns sql.Date`

However, the error is the same

I've been debugging for some time now and I can't seem to find the problem, what am I missing?

Comment: Check your column/value positions. Your 6th-8th column names start with 'date_', denoting that they are of date datatype, which do not match up with the values you are sending. This would be my first guess.

Comment: Nice one I totally missed that! However, they're not dates, my 6th to 8th values are 1 Number and 2 varchars

Comment: Oh wait! That's exactly the problem. I didn't do the query and some fields are missing. Thanks :)

Comment: Glad that fixed it for you. Added comment as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the position of your columns compared to the values you are sending for datatype agreement.